# DevExtreme load JSON as datasource using knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, devextreme

I'm new to both javascript and devextreme and currently finding my way through. I created a webpage which loads a json-file, which worked well, but I can't get it done using devextreme.

I have a dxDataGrid which I want to contain the data. Using a .js-file, that data is also displayed correct. My json-file is this:

```
{
  "user": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "user0",
    "mail": "user0@example.com",
    "address": "examplestreet 0",
    "zip": "12345",
    "city": "examplecity",
    "country": "examplecountry",
    "dayOfBirth": "1990/01/01"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user1",
    "mail": "user1@example.com",
    "address": "examplestreet 1",
    "zip": "23456",
    "city": "examplecity",
    "country": "examplecountry",
    "dayOfBirth": "1990/01/01"
  },
  {      
    "id": 2,
    "name": "user2",
    "mail": "user2@example.com",
    "address": "examplestreet 2",
    "zip": "34567",
    "city": "examplecity",
    "country": "examplecountry",
    "dayOfBirth": "1990/01/01"
  }
 ]
}
```

I tried to load the json-file with the following code, under google chromes developer tools, the object is correctly displayed, but since I am new to this, I can't figure out why it is not loaded into the dxDataGrid.

```
var getData = function () {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                        json;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(json);
            return json;
        }
    };              

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
    xmlhttp.send();


};

var customersViewModel = {
    dataGridOptions: {
        dataSource: getData(),

        editing: {
            allowUpdating: true,
            allowAdding: true,
            mode: "form", 

            form: {
                items: [{
                    itemType: 'group',
                    caption: 'Basisinformationen',
                    items: ['user.name', 'user.mail', {
                        dataField: 'dayOfBirth',
                        editorOptions: {
                            min: new Date(1960,0,1),
                            max: new Date(2010,11,31)
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    itemType: 'group',
                    caption: 'Kontakt',
                    items: ['user.address', 'user.zip', 'user.city', 'user.country']
                }]
            }

        },

        columns: [{
                dataField: 'name',
                caption: 'Name',
                validationRules: [{type: 'required'}]
            }, {
                dataField: 'mail',
                caption: 'E-Mail'
            }, {
                dataField: 'address',
                caption: 'Address'
            }, {
                dataField: 'zip',
                caption: 'Zip-Code'
            }, {
                dataField: 'city',
                caption: 'City'
            }, {
                dataField: 'country',
                caption: 'Country'
            }, {
                dataField: 'dayOfBirth',
                caption: 'Birthdate',
                dataType: 'date',
                format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
            }]
    }
};
return customersViewModel;
```

Thanks for any advice!

Edit: The json-file is working, I can call for example

```
alert(json.user[0].name);
```

and I will get an alert with the text "user0". But how can I implement this functionality into the dataGrid?

Edit 2: I edited my code and came to the following: this code was changed:

```
var getData = function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                        json;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            json = Object.keys(json).map(function (k) { return json[k] });
            console.log(json);
            deferred.resolve(json); // json should be array here
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

The ViewModel() was left as it was. Now, I get the console output:
[image: Console Output]

The dataGrid is still empty though.

Answer (score 1):

The "getData()" method should return a proimise in order to work with dxDataGrid.
Probably something like this:

```
var getData = function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                        json;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(json);
            //return json;
            deferred.resolve(json); // json should be array here
        }
    };              

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

DevExtreme works with JQuery promise. I'm not sure about other promise libraries.

#### Update 1

It looks like you get array of arrays. In this case you need just take first element:

```
deferred.resolve(json[0]); // json should be array here
```

Comment: thank you! I edited my code and edited my question to show you the differences. It's still not showing anything though.

Comment: May be you can try to implement datasource as described in the https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T119195 thread. Or simply try to change "dataSource: getData()," to "items: getData()," ...

Comment: You can check this sample - http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/15_1/Tutorial/UI_Widgets/Use_Remote_Data_for_DataGrid/#Use_Remote_Data_for_DataGrid - looks similar your scenario

Comment: Thanks again, but that doesn't seem to work either. But I figured out what the problem might be. When logging to console, you see the output in the image above. In the working version, the objects are in the top level, like this:    [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]