# DevExtreme / Knockout.js implement JSON as datasource

Tags: javascript, json, rest, knockout.js, devextreme

I'm new to JavaScript and REST, and I need to implement JSON as datasource to devextreme using knockout.js.

My problem is, that I can fetch the json, but it is not added to the datasource. I used `console.log()` for testing and noticed that the json is correctly loaded, but the datasource is empty (see comments in code below). How can I achieve the usage of my json as datasource?

Note: I used [DevExtreme load JSON as datasource using knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659637/devextreme-load-json-as-datasource-using-knockout) as base for getting my JSON-contents.

I have a sample JSON-File looking like this:

```
{
    "ID":"3",
    "content":
    {
        "ProdId":"000176491264",
        "ProdDesc":"Sample 1",
        "Type":"A",
    }
}
```

And my current viewmodel looks like this:

```
MyApp.overview = function (params) {
    "use strict";

    var getData = function () {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), json;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                // prints needed content:
                console.log(json.content);
                deferred.resolve(json.content);
            }
         };              

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost:56253/test/3?format=json', true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        return deferred.promise();
    };

    var viewModel = {
        overviewDatagridOptions: {

            dataSource: getData(),

            selection: {
            mode: "single"
            },

            columns: [{
                dataField: "ProdId",
                caption: "ID"
            }, {
                dataField: "ProdDesc",
                caption: "Description"
            }, {
                dataField: "Type",
                caption: "Type"
            }],

            rowAlternationEnabled: true
        },

        // Returns {}
        console.log("Datasource: " + JSON.stringify(viewModel.overviewDatagridOptions.dataSource));
        return viewModel;
    };
```

Edit: I changed my datasource to this:

```
dataSource: {
    load: function (loadOptions) {
        var d = new $.Deferred();
        var params = {};
        //Getting filter options
        if (loadOptions.filter)  {
            params.filter = JSON.stringify(loadOptions.filter);
        }
        //Getting sort options
        if (loadOptions.sort)  {
            params.sort = JSON.stringify(loadOptions.sort);
        }    
        //Getting dataField option
        if (loadOptions.dataField)  {
            params.dataField = loadOptions.dataField;
        }         
        //If the select expression is specified
        if (loadOptions.select)  {
            params.select= JSON.stringify(loadOptions.select);
        } 
        //Getting group options
        if (loadOptions.group)  {
            params.group = JSON.stringify(loadOptions.group);
        } 

        //skip and take are used for paging
        params.skip = loadOptions.skip; //A number of records that should be skipped
        params.take = loadOptions.take; //A number of records that should be taken
        var obj;
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:56253/test/3?format=json', params).done(function (data) {

        d.resolve(data);

        });
        //return obj;
        return d.promise();
    }, [...]
```

Based on the demo found here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18955

Now, the output from  the datasource is no longer empty, and looks like this:

```
Object
- load:(loadOptions)
  - arguments:(...)
  - caller:(...)
  - length:1
  - name:"load"
  - prototype:Object
  - __proto__:()
  - [[FunctionLocation]]
  - [[Scopes]]:Scopes[1]
- totalCount:(loadOptions)
  - arguments:(...)
  - caller:(...)
  - length:1
  - name:"totalCount"
  - prototype:Object
  - __proto__:()
  - [[FunctionLocation]]
  - [[Scopes]]:Scopes[1]
  - __proto__:Object
```

Comment: Where are you calling dataSource.load()?

Comment: @JasonSpake I think load() is called automatically by the store-object. For testing, I called it manually but without any changes.

Comment: Have you tried using ajax? @Marcel

Comment: @Girl_engineer as I mentioned above, I'm currently learning JS, the above is what I tried using, so no ajax yet. Any suggestions on implementing that?